# No OpenId endpoint found wordpress

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, login, sign-up

I'm getting this when I try to sign up for academia.se:

[image]

Comment: Looks the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148923/unable-to-log-in-with-your-openid-provider-no-openid-endpoint-found ; my delegated OpenID isn't working either. Did they break logins completely?

Comment: Yeah, looks like delegation is busted. Must be recent - I just used my own delegated OpenID a couple days ago. **[Edit:** if you use the new openid2.* links to delegate, things work just fine. If you use the old form, they don't work at all. **]**

Comment: For those converting their delegation links, `openid.server` is now `openid2.provider`, and `openid.delegate` is now `openid2.local_id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We updated DotNetOpenAuth (the library we use for OpenId authentication) to version 4 recently. Something in that update broke OpenId 1 delegation (which Wordpress uses); OpenId 2 delegation continued to work (as Shog9 notes in a comment on your question).

We'll have to figure out whether this is a problem in DNOA or if we just screwed up something; for the time being, I have reverted the update. It should be back to working everywhere now.

Comment: Confirmed that it works now.