# Can't login to Careers (delegated OpenID)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, openid, login

I got an e-mail suggestion to update my profile from Stack Overflow Careers. I went to log in and got this error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

I can log in normally on Stack Overflow. I have never seen this error before, and I have not recently changed anything about my OpenID arrangements.

My OpenID URL is `http://switchb.org/kpreid/`. Tried on Safari 6.0 (7536.25) and on Chrome 24.0.1297.0 dev.

Comment: We're looking into this... will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed - OpenID 1 delegation works again.

Answer (score 2):

My version 1 OpenID doesn't work either, but version 2 does. The new version of DotNetOpenAuth [broke the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148938/145982) a few weeks ago; they might still be running it on Careers.

For now, you can add version 2 links to your website:

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.livejournal.com/openid/server.bml">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://kpreid.livejournal.com/">
```